# How to open pdf file from J2ME Application?

Tags: java-me

We are developing one J2ME Application and we need to open usermanual.pdf file which stored locally.
I already use below code which download pdf file from internet and open it in browser

```
platformRequest("http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.1/cldc11api.pdf");
```

but i keep this file in some local folder and pass the path as below 
platformRequest("file://localhost/My Device/My Documents/ftp/test.pdf");
but i didn't open in browser or in reader.

I just want to open it in Acrobat Reader which already installed in Motorola MC65 device.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [J2ME Content Handler API, JSR 211](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/21958)